# доступ к истории команд в консоли

Tags: c, база-данных, алгоритм, строки, список

У меня есть введенные строки.

Когда я нажимаю enter, мне нужно сохранить куда-то строку, затем через стрелки иметь доступ к ним.

Я хочу это реализовать через open/read/write/lseek. Но есть одно "но": я не совсем понимаю как быть с размерами строк (чтобы удобнее пользоваться lseek).

Я думаю, что мне, скорее всего, нужен будет массив типа стека для размещения размеров предыдущих команд, и, в таком случае, мне нужен будет дополнительный файл, который я заполню как массивом из предыдущих размеров при выходе, и при запуске программы заполнять массив из файла.

Если индекс массива подходит к концу (2000 команд, допустим), то передвигать всё на одну позицию назад, затем пересоздавать файл с размерами и пересоздавать файл с историями, удаляя первую команду оттуда.
И так будет постоянно, если размер стека дойдет до 2000 значений, - это и есть яма этого решения. Как её можно обойти?

Comment: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартным способом будет задать максимальное количество строк N=2000  и при достижении лимита чистить историю пополам до N=1000. Чистка истории будет очень редко и никто не заметит проблем.

*Усовершенствование:*

Два файла истории, каждый по 1000 строк. Два фала индексов. При переполнении до 2000 строк очищаются старый файл строк и индексов. И остаётся только 1000. Не будет никакой нагрузки для вычисления новых индексов. Быстро и коротко.

```
Ab     Gh             Gh     Mn
Cd  ;  Ij  +  Mn  =>  Ij  ;
..     ..             ..
Ef     Kl             Kl
```

Comment: Способ хороший, но ведь bash, например, так не делает?)) Можно в принципе продолжать после загрузки 2000 строк вести дальше счет, просто при завершении программы лишние, допустим 500 из 2500 удалить, перезаписав файлы.

Comment: не знаю как `bash` и `history` делают, мне нравится исполнение с двумя файлами.

Comment: Интересное усовершенствование, спасибо ) Подумаю еще, может что придет в голову ) А вообще я думал мне кто-то сейчас раскроет сакральный, волшебный и элементарный метод работы read для строк без lseek (ну типа с символом переноса строк связанный) :DDD

Comment: Есть ли способ сделать так, что бы файл индексов видела только программа? Что бы пользователь, допустим, не мог его просто взять и удалить обычными способами. Я думаю о правах 0600, мол для владельца только, а как еще можно?

Comment: просто сделать файлы, начинающихся с точки и юзер просто не увидит. А сложно может быть и не надо..

Comment: Произойдет кек, если удалён хоть один символ из файла истории )) спасибо за помощь) про точку я тоже думал )